# remove addEventListener for font-weight - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I created javascript eventListener by using javascript for my dropdown link. When I click on 'bold', everything turn bold. It is ok for me but I want to remove it when clicking. When I click again, my removeListener does not work, it is missing something I guess.

Thank you in advance.

```
//HTML

          <nav class="navBar">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn"  id="dropbutton">Style menu</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#" class="bold">Bold</a>
                    <a href="#" class="italic">Italic</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn"  id="dropbutton1">Thèmes site</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#" class="fonce">Fonce</a>
                    <a href="#" class="pale">Pale</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


// JAVASCRIPT

const bold = document.querySelector(".bold");
const italic = document.querySelector(".italic");
const fonce = document.querySelector(".fonce");

function Mystyle(){
   bold.style.fontWeight = "bold";
   italic.style.fontWeight = "bold";
   fonce.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  
};

bold.addEventListener("click", Mystyle);


// It does not work
function removeEvent() {
    bold.removeEventListener("click", Mystyle);
  }
```

Comment: you are not calling your `removeEvent()` anywhere in the provided code

Comment: removerEvent() I put below 'bold.addEventListener("click", Mystyle);" but nothing works

Comment: You do not call `removeEvent` anywhere. And removing an event listener is not going to unbold the text. It is not going to undo anything that happened in the click.

Comment: @Alex if you do that then your `bold.addEventListener("click", Mystyle);` will do nothing because it will remove the event right after you added it and nothing will turn bold after you click the button. You should toggle a class like the answer below suggested

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG. Where do you suggest me to put removeEvent()?

Comment: @Alex drop that function and go for what the answer suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not remove the event listener; instead, change the styles (or toggle a class) depending on the current state for each click.

```js
function Mystyle(){
    if (bold.style.fontWeight === 'bold')
        bold.style.fontWeight = italic.style.fontWeight = fonce.style.fontWeight = "";
    else
        bold.style.fontWeight = italic.style.fontWeight = fonce.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  
};
bold.addEventListener("click", Mystyle);
```

It is more convenient to toggle a class instead:

```js
function Mystyle() {
  document.querySelector('.navBar').classList.toggle('bold');
}
document.querySelector('.bold').addEventListener("click", Mystyle);
```

```css
.navBar.bold .bold, .navBar.bold .italic, .navBar.bold .fonce {
/* or perhaps use .navBar.bold a */
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navBar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="dropbutton">Style menu</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" class="bold">Bold</a>
      <a href="#" class="italic">Italic</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" id="dropbutton1">Thèmes site</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#" class="fonce">Fonce</a>
      <a href="#" class="pale">Pale</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```